# laravel-echo-server docker - Нет связи между контейнерами

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-echo

Не могу настроить соединения с echo server
Сам echo server находится в отдельном контейнере.

Сервер запускается но соединения не устанавливается, тоже самое на Open server работает.
Не могу понять в чём проблема, возможно ошибка в хосте или порте, пробовал много вариантов но не смог понять куда смотреть. Префикс редиса убрал.  'prefix' => '',

Ответ в консоли

```
app.js:14933 WebSocket connection to 'ws://lara-docker.loc:6001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed:
```

Конфиги

**docker-compose**

```
version: "3.5"

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  nginx-service:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nxing-container
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
      - ./docker/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    networks:
      - laravel
    depends_on:
      - fpm
      - node

    # mysql
  mysql-service:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - 33061:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=laravel
    volumes:
      - ./docker/db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  fpm:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./php/Dockerfile
    container_name: fpm
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
    networks:
      - laravel

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - laravel

  redis:
    image: "redis:3.2"
    command: "redis-server --appendonly yes"
    networks:
      - laravel
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  node:
    depends_on:
      - fpm
      - redis
    container_name: node
    build:
      context: ./docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        buildno: 1
        gitcommithash: cdc3b19
    env_file: docker/.env
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
    #environment:
    #  - TYPE=${TYPE}
    networks:
      - laravel
```

**Конфиг nginx**

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name lara-docker.loc;
    client_max_body_size 300M;
    root /var/www/public;
    index index.php;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    if ($request_uri ~ ^/([^/]*)/.*$ ) {
        set $virtualdir /$1;
    }

    if (-d "$document_root$virtualdir") {
        set $realdir "${virtualdir}";
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }

    location /socket.io {
        proxy_pass http://node:6001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {

        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

**Bootstap.js**

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"
window.io = require('socket.io-client');
if (typeof io !== 'undefined') {
  window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001',
    transports: ['websocket', 'polling', 'flashsocket']
  });
}
```

**laravel-echo-server***

```
{
    "authHost": "http://nginx:80",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {
            "port": "6379",
            "host": "redis",
            "keyPrefix": ""
        },
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "secureOptions": 67108864,
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": false,
        "allowOrigin": "",
        "allowMethods": "",
        "allowHeaders": ""
    }
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:lts-slim

WORKDIR /var/www


RUN  npm i -g laravel-echo-server 

EXPOSE 6001

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/script.sh"]
CMD ["laravel-echo-server", "start"]
```

Возможно кто-то уже сталкивался, и сможет подсказать куда смотреть
Возможно не верно сделаны настройки в nginx

```
  location /socket.io {
        proxy_pass http://node:6001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }
```

Или в laravel-echo-server.json - значение authHost
`"authHost": "http://nginx:80",`

Comment: Попробуйте убрать server_name, оставив default

Comment: Спасибо за совет, убрал. Но не помогло. Хотя сам сервер события видит, но не передаёт,
https://prnt.sc/1wj0kny

Comment: Выполните `docker-compose ps` - так увидите какие порты открыты. Порт 6001 на хост-машину не проброшен => работать не будет

Comment: PS. Вместо ноды можно использовать PHP пакет [beyondcode/laravel-websockets](https://packagist.org/packages/beyondcode/laravel-websockets).

Comment: @TotalPusher спасибо за совет, добавил проброс в docker-compose для контейнера Node

 
    ports:
      - "6001:6001"

https://prnt.sc/1wlvgy5

Всё равно не работает, 
что я не так сделал, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Ошибка точно такая же, или уже другая? Также покажите что там происходит при отправке запроса, это можно увидеть на вкладке сеть.

Comment: Также я не понял, вы хотите через nginx коннектиться, или напрямую в контейнер node? `location /socket.io`, `"authHost": "http://nginx:80"`, а в другом месте `host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'`. А в ошибке - коннект к 6001 порту. У вас все тут запутано.

Comment: В network у ответов появились заголовки, network - https://prnt.sc/1wm6zt0 консоль - https://prnt.sc/1wm7o4s, но в консоли ошибки соединения. Вы правы насчёт разные хостов, я и не могу понять, от чего нужно отталкиваться при заполнении
bootstap.js - значение host 
authHost - в конфиге эхо

Подскажите пожалуйста чем тут руководствоваться. Кажется что authHost должен делать запрос в fpm, но тогда получается в echo клиенте нужно прописывать контейнер node?